# PHP foreach not displaying results

Tags: php, html, twitter

I have a script that scrapes the Twitter search API and returns the results the URL's in a tweet. However, it is currently returning no results. Why is this?

```
$search = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23google%20vine.co%2Fv%2F&result_type=recent&include_entities=1&rpp=10'));

foreach($search->results as $result) {
    echo $result->urls->expanded_url.'<br>';
}
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Start by debugging your return array.  `var_dump($search)` to see what, if anything, it contains.

Comment: There is no property `urls` in the `result` object....

Comment: `$result->entities->urls` is an array of objects. then you need to loop over that.

Comment: @user2036031 see popnoodles answer below. You need a second loop inside your first loop (and that what he as posted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with

```
foreach($search->results as $result) {
    foreach($result->entities->urls as $url){
        echo $url->expanded_url.'<br>';
    }
}
```

$search->results is an array of objects, you have to iterate also this one

Comment: @user2036031 since it's working, why not to accept the answer?

Comment: because some people who ask questions on here want you to provide an exact answer without them having to think for themselves, and afterwards are totally ungrateful

Comment: @popnoodles mah, if somebody needs help because at that moment can't find a solution it's ok for me, I did it so many times ^^ I'd just like to earn some reputation!

Comment: It's one thing asking a question but when enough info is  given and the ask "yeah but how do i get expanded_url" without even trying it grates.